# How can I use cython to speed up the numpy?

Tags: numpy, cython

I followed the instruction in 
http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html

But I met some problem when I was trying to build my own block:

(The code's purpose is just calculate the union area of two triangle)

My .pyx code:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

cpdef DTYPE_t union(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] au, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] bu, DTYPE_t area_intersection):
    cdef DTYPE_t area_a
    cdef DTYPE_t area_b
    cdef DTYPE_t area_union
    cdef DTYPE_t a = au[2]
    cdef DTYPE_t b = au[0]
    cdef DTYPE_t c = au[3]
    cdef DTYPE_t d = au[1]
    cdef DTYPE_t e = bu[2]
    cdef DTYPE_t f = bu[0]
    cdef DTYPE_t g = bu[3]
    cdef DTYPE_t h = bu[1]
    area_a = (a - b) * (c - d)
    area_b = (e - f) * (g - h)
    area_union = area_a + area_b - area_intersection
    return area_union
```

My .py code

```
import numpy as np
import random


def union(au, bu,area_intersection):
    area_a = (au[2] - au[0]) * (au[3] - au[1])
    area_b = (bu[2] - bu[0]) * (bu[3] - bu[1])
    area_union = area_a + area_b - area_intersection
    return area_union
```

My setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('union.pyx'),include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

I used the following code to test the speed of cython:

```
from union_py import union as py_speed
from union import union as cy_speed
import numpy as np
import time

np.random.seed(1)
start = time.time()
for i in range (1000000):
    in_a = np.random.rand(4)
    in_b = np.random.rand(4)
    c = cy_speed(au = in_a,bu = in_b,area_intersection = 2.1)

end = time.time()
print (end - start)
```

For the python speed, I just change the `cy_speed` to `py_speed`.

The outcome shows that the cython takes `2.291128158569336` and python takes `2.0604214668273926` . The python version is even faster. I made sure that the cython code's functionality(calculate the union area) is correct. How can I improve the cython code to speed up?

Comment: Now your timings include also creation of numpy arrays, what do you see, when your timings only include the actual calculation?

Comment: My feeling is that the function is trivial enough that Cython's type checking will always be slower than any speed gains in the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

DavidW's feeling is right: The cython has to check the types of the passed arrays during the run-time and this means an overhead which cannot be recovered due to very few operations in the function itself.

The numpy-array isn't the best choice for this task - using cdef-classes, as we will see, can beat python by a factor of 10.

For my experiments I'm using a slightly different set-up:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.random.rand(4)
>>> b=np.random.rand(4)

>>> %timeit py_union(a,b,2.1)
1.3 µs ± 51.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>> %timeit cy_union(a,b,2.1)
1.39 µs ± 11.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So the cython version is really somewhat slower. As DavidW has pointed out, it is due to the cython's type checking, when we look at the generated C-code, before the first line of function is evaluated, the following must happen:

```
...
__Pyx_LocalBuf_ND __pyx_pybuffernd_au;
...
if (unlikely(__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate(&__pyx_pybuffernd_au.rcbuffer->pybuffer, (PyObject*)__pyx_v_au, &__Pyx_TypeInfo_nn___pyx_t_3foo_DTYPE_t, PyBUF_FORMAT| PyBUF_STRIDES, 1, 0, __pyx_stack) == -1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 7, __pyx_L1_error)
```

The definition of `__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate` can be found [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/56aa4c15a8af6e6cfe8a92ed1b30b36b512eb477/Cython/Utility/Buffer.c#L182), and we can easily see, that it isn't for free.

Let's verify it with two experiments. First reducing the number of operation in the function:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

cpdef DTYPE_t cy_silly1(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] au, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] bu, DTYPE_t area_intersection):
    area_union = au[0] + bu[1] - area_intersection
    return area_union

>>> %timeit cy_silly1(a,b,2.1)
1.4 µs ± 12.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

We reduced the number of operation in the function, but it had no impact on the execution time, i.e. this part of the function isn't the bottle-neck.

And what happens if we would have only one numpy-array to check?

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

cpdef DTYPE_t cy_silly2(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] au, DTYPE_t area_intersection):
    cdef DTYPE_t area_union = au[0] + au[1] - area_intersection
    return area_union

>>> %timeit cy_silly2(a,2.1)
745 ns ± 7.46 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

This time we get almost speedup 2 - `__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate` is really the bottle-neck.

What can be done? [Typed memory views](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) have slightly less overhead, because they use a totally different machinery:

```
%%cython
...
cpdef DTYPE_t cy_union_tmv(DTYPE_t[::1] au, DTYPE_t[::1] bu, DTYPE_t area_intersection):
...#the same as above

%timeit cy_union_tmv(a,b,2.1)
1.09 µs ± 3.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

A better idea would be to write a dedicated cdef-class which would have much less overhead:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

cdef class Triangle:
   cdef DTYPE_t a
   cdef DTYPE_t b
   cdef DTYPE_t c
   cdef DTYPE_t d
   def __init__(self, a,b,c,d):
      self.a=a
      self.b=b
      self.c=c
      self.d=d
   cdef DTYPE_t get_area(self):
      return (self.a-self.b)*(self.c-self.d)


cpdef DTYPE_t cy_union_cdef(Triangle au, Triangle bu, DTYPE_t area_intersection):
    cdef DTYPE_t area_union = au.get_area() + bu.get_area() - area_intersection 
    return area_union
```

And now:

```
>>> tri_a=Triangle(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3])
>>> tri_b=Triangle(b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]) 
>>> %timeit cy_union_cdef(tri_a,tri_b,2.1)
106 ns ± 0.668 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

yields a speedup of about 10.

Answer (score 1):

**Avoiding function call overhead**

You are calling a very simple function. If you do that in C the compiler hopefully inlines this simple function to avoid function call overhead (which is far less than calling a python function)

I guess that your `in_a`,`in_b` and `in_b` and `area_intersection` are stored in arrays in a real world example. In this case you have to pass the whole arrays to a compiled function.

In the following example I will show a simple example on using numba on such tasks, which can also inlines simple functions. This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but will make the job quite a bit easier and can if preferred taken as a template for a efficient cython implementation.

As already mentioned, the random number generation dominates the runtime of your benchmark. To avoid this, I will generate the random numbers outside the benchmark.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

#comment for python Testing, don't use cache when copying the function
#to the interpreter
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def union(au, bu,area_intersection):
  area_a = (au[2] - au[0]) * (au[3] - au[1])
  area_b = (bu[2] - bu[0]) * (bu[3] - bu[1])
  area_union = area_a + area_b - area_intersection
  return area_union

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def Union_Arr(in_a,in_b,area_intersection):
  c=np.empty(in_a.shape[0],dtype=in_a.dtype)
  for i in range (in_a.shape[0]):
    c[i] = union(in_a[i,:],in_b[i,:],area_intersection[i])

  return c

#generating testdata
np.random.seed(1)
in_a = np.random.rand(1000000,4)
in_b = np.random.rand(1000000,4)
area_intersection = np.random.rand(1000000)

#Warm up
#even loading cached native code takes a while,
#we don't want to measure a constant overhead (about 60ms)
#in a performance critical code segment, that is called many times
c=Union_Arr(in_a,in_b,area_intersection)

start = time.time()
c=Union_Arr(in_a,in_b,area_intersection)
end = time.time()
print (end - start)
```

**Results for 1 million triangles per call**

Pure Python: 1.92s for 1,000,000 triangles (1.92 µs per triangle intersection)

Numba: 0.007s for 1,000,000 triangles (7 ns per triangle intersection)

In summary, it can be stated that it is crucial to avoid calling tiny functions from non compiled code. Even the optimized function from @ead is more than a magnitude slower than the example above.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to calculate areas for a batch of triangles and not for single triangles. Whether one uses numba or cython - the result will be similar fast, because of a very small overhead.